# TypeError: can't convert return value to desired type

Tags: python-3.x, webkit

When I run my python script I get the following console output:

```
TypeError: can't convert return value to desired type
```

The script does what I except and I have no clue where this message comes from. How can I find out which line contains the code that triggers the message in order to isolate the cause?

**EDIT:**

A minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import gi
import os
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import getopt
import sys
from gi.repository import Gtk,WebKit

#resolve the file url
fileUri = 'test.html'
fileUri = os.path.realpath(fileUri)
fileUri = urllib.parse.ParseResult('file', '', fileUri, '', '', '')
fileUri = urllib.parse.urlunparse(fileUri)

def navrequest(thisview, frame, networkRequest):
    address = networkRequest.get_uri()

    if not fileUri in address:
        md = Gtk.MessageDialog(win,0,Gtk.MessageType.INFO, Gtk.ButtonsType.CLOSE, "Not allowed to leave the site!")

        md.run()
        md.destroy()
        view.open(fileUri)

view = WebKit.WebView()
view.connect("navigation-requested", navrequest)

sw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
sw.add(view)

vbox = Gtk.VBox()
vbox.add(sw)

win = Gtk.Window()
win.set_size_request(800, 600)
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.set_title("TypeErrortest")
win.add(vbox)
win.show_all()

view.open(fileUri) 
Gtk.main()
```

test.hmtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The complete console output:

```
[me ~]$ ./testTypeError.py 
TypeError: can't convert return value to desired type
[me ~]$
```

Operating System: Arch Linux

Version: Python 3.4.2

Comment: Can you add your script to your question?

Comment: Is that the entirety of the error message?  The lines immediately before it should include a stack trace.

Comment: Edited my question and added a minimal example. I see no stack trace.

Comment: I was not aware that there should be a stack trace in this case. What does it mean if it is not there?

Comment: The lack of stack trace probably means that the error is in a callback.  Perhaps `navrequest` should return something other than None.  I know nothing about Webkit, but would look in the `Webview.connect` doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of the function handling the signal was the problem. Adding a `return 0` to the `navrequest` function made the message disappear.